# How to add Oracle JVM arguments to Tomcat execution

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm using an Oracle 11G version on my application, which is an Apache Tomcat server.

Some users have issues with some queries to the database when they use a specific time zone, like ETC/Universal for example. Oracle throws following exception:

> ORA-01882: timezone region not found

I found a workaround for this problem. There is a specific argument that needs to be given to the JVM when it starts:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```

I want to put this in the configuration of Tomcat.
I need a Windows and a Linux solution. Where can I put this setting?

Comment: This looks like a start up argument but are you sure Tomcat will understand **oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the JVM arguments in the startup script of tomcat (usually catalina.bat or catalina.sh).

For Windows (catalina.bat)

```
set JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false"
```

for linux (catalina.sh)

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

Also you can Update the file `oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties`(i.e. inside your jar - **ojdbc7.jar or classes12.jar**) in whatever version of the library  you are using to contain the line below:

```
oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```